# RazorLight RazorLight.TemplateNotFoundException: Project can not find template with key

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, razor, razorengine, razorlight

I am trying to generate HTML based on a .cshtml file, which is embedded:

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="Templates\ReportTemplate.cshtml" />
```

However, from RazorLight I always get the following Exception:

```
 RazorLight.TemplateNotFoundException: Project can not find template with key My.Namespace.Application.Templates.ReportTemplate.cshtml
   at RazorLight.Compilation.RazorTemplateCompiler.CreateRuntimeCompilationWorkItem(String templateKey)
   at RazorLight.Compilation.RazorTemplateCompiler.OnCacheMissAsync(String templateKey)
   at RazorLight.Compilation.RazorTemplateCompiler.CompileAsync(String templateKey)
   at RazorLight.EngineHandler.CompileTemplateAsync(String key)
   at RazorLight.EngineHandler.CompileRenderAsync[T](String key, T model, ExpandoObject viewBag)
```

But when I check the embedded resources, I can clearly see the embedded resource :

```
string[] files = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
```

`files` contains: **My.Namespace.Application.Templates.ReportTemplate.cshtml**

Here is my code to generate the PDF:

```
private async Task<string> RenderRazorTemplate(string key, Type viewModelType, object viewModel)
    {

        string[] files = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();
        var engine = new RazorLightEngineBuilder()
            .UseEmbeddedResourcesProject(Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly()) // Use the Executing Assembly as project that embeds the .cshtml templates
            .SetOperatingAssembly(viewModelType.Assembly) // Without this, you'll get a Exception saying that the Assembly can't find the AntiForgery.dll
            .UseMemoryCachingProvider()
            .Build();
        
        return await engine.CompileRenderAsync(key, viewModel);
    }
```

My parameters are:
Key: **My.Namespace.Application.Templates.ReportTemplate.cshtml**

I am using `RazorLight.NetCore3` Version `3.0.2`

Comment: For the error of "Project can not find template with key", you can refer to this article, which may be helpful to you:https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight/issues/378.More use of RazorLight:https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight